# How to get rowObject from rowId using jQGrid and lib.web.mvc

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid

I am using lib.web.mvc jQGrid helper.

I can get the rowId from a row in jqgrid using

onSelectRow: "SelectedRowHandler",

```
    function SelectedRowHandler(rowId) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Invoice/selectedRow',
            data: { id: rowId }
        });
        return true;

    }
```

But I need to get the rowObject so I can get the Id of the database record.

Is there an easy way rather than processing the rowId.

Answer (score 0):

I got this from [Oleg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/315935/oleg)

```
var rowData = this.p.data[this.p._index[rowId]];
```